# libGTM_NSData+zlib.a not found xCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoapods

I am getting the following error when I try to build my project:

```
ld: file not found: /..../Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib.a
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The problem is that in my project I have not "GoogleUtilities" folder (and I dont want to use it). Here is my pod file:

```
pod 'Braintree', '~> 3.3'
pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

I can not understand why xcode looks at this directory? I guess that something i should change in project building settings, but i have not idea how to do that.

Comment: Did you add previously a Google Pod ?

Comment: I'm not the author of that code, i just try to fix some bugs (like this :) ). I guess that initially Google pods were included in project

Comment: You can try by removing the pod (deintegrate or something, check the doc), and reinstall them.

Comment: I have tried it already, but it does not solve the problem. After reinstalling I'm not getting /Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/ folder

Comment: Look for "GTM_NSData" in your projects settings/pods settings. My guess is that someone hard coded that value to fix something, and when it was removed, oops.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking at project settings but I still can't find it can be hard coded.